# Possible ERC-20 improvement: Token-specific ENS equivalent

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20, mapping, ens

With ENS still providing quite a difficult user experience for the average user, I'm wondering why standards like ERC-20 don't implement a simple mapping allowing people to set names equivalent to their addresses for that specific token contract.

I have a couple of ENS addresses, and barely ever use them, partly because even those who know a lot about Ethereum might not know about ENS properly. So then I thought, why have I not seen tokens (they might exist, I just haven't seen them), implemented this functionality to provide a better user experience? In talking about this, the arguments came up that "wallets would have to adapt for this" and "it is very limited since it is token-specific", which are very valid points indeed. However, I wonder if it is not worth considering this approach while ENS is still not widely-adopted?

See below for a simple implementation of this on an ERC-20 token contract, as an example, but without much thought having been given to the functionalities:

```
pragma solidity^0.4.25;

contract TestToken {

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require (msg.sender == owner); {
        _;
    }
}

mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping (string => address) names;
mapping (string => uint) nameValue;

string public name = "Test Token";
string public symbol = "TTT";
uint8 public decimals = 18;
uint price;

uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000 * (uint256(10) ** decimals);

event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

address owner;

constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    balanceOf[owner] = totalSupply;
    emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, totalSupply);
    price = 1 ether;
}

function setName(string _name) public payable {
    require (msg.value >= price);
    require (names[_name] == address(0));
    names[_name] = msg.sender;
    nameValue[_name] = msg.value;
}

function sellName(string _name) public {
    require (names[_name] == msg.sender);
    names[_name] = address(0);
    uint value = nameValue[_name];
    nameValue[_name] = 0;
    msg.sender.transfer(value);
}

function getAddress(string _name) public view returns (address) {
    return names[_name];
}

function transfer(address _to, string _name, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= value);
    address to;
    if (bytes(_name).length > 0) {
        to = names[_name];
    }
    else {
        to = _to;
    }
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= value;  
    balanceOf[to] += value;          
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
    return true;
}

event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);

mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

function approve(address _spender, string _name, uint256 value)
    public
    returns (bool success)
{
    address spender;
    if (bytes(_name).length > 0) {
        spender = names[_name];
    }
    else {
        spender = _spender;
    }
    allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address from, address _to, string _name, uint256 value)
    public
    returns (bool success)
{
    require(value <= balanceOf[from]);
    require(value <= allowance[from][msg.sender]);
    address to;
    if (bytes(_name).length > 0) {
        to = names[_name];
    }
    else {
        to = _to;
    }
    balanceOf[from] -= value;
    balanceOf[to] += value;
    allowance[from][msg.sender] -= value;
    emit Transfer(from, to, value);
    return true;
}

function burnFrom(address _burned, string _name, uint _tokens) public onlyOwner {
    address burned;
    if (bytes(_name).length > 0) {
        burned = names[_name];
    }
    else {
        burned = _burned;
    }
    balanceOf[burned] -= _tokens;
}

function nameBalance(string _name) public view returns(uint) {
    return balanceOf[names[_name]];
}
}
```

Let me know what you think, I'm interested in a discussion about the pros and cons of this.

Comment: What is your question? I'd suggest to try posting this in reddit or other social network.